# How to call form in template when using generic.FormView in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is my form class:
from django import forms

```
from .models import Category


class AddResource(forms.Form):

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [cat.title for cat in Category.objects.all()]

    ResourceTitle = forms.CharField()
    Description = forms.Textarea()
    Link = forms.URLField()
    Categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

This is my view for the form URL:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, FormView

from .models import *
from .forms import AddResource


class AddResourceView(FormView):

    template_name = 'addRes.html'
    form_class = AddResource
    success_url = '/'

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        return form_class()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print form
        return super(AddResourceView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The trouble that I'm having is calling this inside templates. How do I call the form that I assigned inside of django-templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Its how you include choices in django forms. So `CATEGORY_CHOICES` has to be a list of tuples, which it was not in this case.

Thus, this simple change made it work:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [('', cat.title)
                    for cat in Category.objects.all()]
```

Comment: You should change that to `(cat.title, cat.get_title_display())`. Right now you will see visually distinct options, but you'll send an empty string to the server no matter what option you select. Choices should be a list of tuples of the form `[(value, display_value)]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `FormView` supplies a context variable called `form` that holds your actual form object, so you can use:

```
{{ form.as_table }}
```

Or any of the other rendering options that `form` supplies. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Also, why do you overwrite `get_form` like that?